# Combine and sort multiple array columns of values A and B where A is the common index

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, sorting

I have a n-long list of arrays. Each array consists of two columns:
A) index values between 1-500
B) measured values

Each A column is slightly different (i.e. missing or having extra values).

I want to create single large array where i) there is single A (index) column consisting of all the index values and ii) all the B (measured values) columns appropriately sorted, so they are in the same row as the original index value. The missing values would be filled with nan or 0s.

Array examples:

```
#         A      B
arr1 = np.array([[  25,    64],
                 [  45,    26]])

arr2 = np.array([[ 8,     54],
                [  25,     2],
                [  45,    84],
                [  128,   22]])

arr3 = np.array([[ 17,   530],
                 [255,    25]])
```

Array of my dreams:

```
#                   A          B  
#                      arr1  arr2  arr3
dreamArr = array([[8,     0,   54,    0],
                  [17,    0,    0,  530],
                  [25,   64,    2,    0],
                  [45,   26,   84,    0],
                  [128,   0,   22,    0],
                  [255,   0,     0,  25]])
```

I tried creating an `np.zeros()` array and replaced the individual columns with small arrays and got stuck.

Then I tried getting all the A values upfront by `np.vstack()`, removed duplicates with `np.unique`, `np.sort()`ed them and got stuck again.

All input is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you need a solution that only uses `numpy`, or can you use other libraries, like `pandas`? (which would make the solution considerably simpler)

Comment: `pandas` would do as well. That being said, I'm still curious whether there's a `numpy` way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple using [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas):

```
import pandas as pd

arrs = [arr1, arr2, arr3]

out = (pd
 .concat([pd.DataFrame(a).set_index(0) for a in arrs], axis=1)
 .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
 .sort_index().reset_index().to_numpy()
)
```

output:

```
array([[  8,   0,  54,   0],
       [ 17,   0,   0, 530],
       [ 25,  64,   2,   0],
       [ 45,  26,  84,   0],
       [128,   0,  22,   0],
       [255,   0,   0,  25]])
```